# Engine randomly turns off on Mazda Capella 2000

Tags: engine, mazda, stall

Recently I have been having some issues with my Mazda Capella 2000 occasionally just switching off while I am at low revs. It doesn't often happen but when it does it seems to happen multiple times in a row.

Always happens at low revs, it happens while driving during things like stopping at an intersection or slowing down to turn into a driveway. It gives no warning when it stops, it just switches off, No choking noises like the engine is having trouble or any other indication that it is going to happen. The battery light turns on (like it is before you start the engine) and when I start the engine it always starts again straight away (but the problem often persists for awhile and if you don't rev it it will switch off again).

Doesn't seem to make a difference whether the car is hot or cold. I thought that perhaps it might happen when I park on a slope but this might be coincidence as parking on a slope doesn't always seem to cause the issue.

Any thoughts on what could possibly be going on?

If you have any questions please let me know.

Comment: Did you ever get this fixed?

Comment: @Paulster2 Not yet unfortunately, it doesn't happen too often and while difficult it is possible to drive while it is happening. You just have to keep revving it when you come to intersections and after driving like that for 5-10 minutes it seems to come right. It also seems to happen less often as long as I keep more that 1/4 of petrol in the tank (probably only happens like once a month now). My best guess is either the fuel pump failing or something weird like water in the tank. Does that sound likely to you?

Comment: I actually agree with you on the fuel pump. You could put a fuel pressure gauge on the car and see what it is reading when it does this strange behavior.

Comment: Hmm thanks, I'll see what I can do and I'll let you know.

Comment: I never ended up getting this fixed but I did discover a solution. I found that if I revved the engine (while in neutral) really high a couple of times it would fix the issue straight away.

Comment: That's really strange ... maybe that'll be a clue to someone who can help with the issue. I'm glad you at least have a workaround.